# When I use httplib for my OAUTH in Python, I always get "CannotSendRequest" and then "

Tags: python, django, connection, oauth, httplib

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ea/ea/hell/life/views.py" in linkedin_auth
  274.     token = oauth_linkedin.get_unauthorised_request_token()
File "/home/ea/ea/hell/life/oauth_linkedin.py" in get_unauthorised_request_token
  52.     resp = fetch_response(oauth_request, connection)
File "/home/ea/ea/hell/life/oauth_linkedin.py" in fetch_response
  42.         connection.request(oauth_request.http_method,url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in request
  874.             self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in _send_request
  891.         self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in putrequest
  778.             raise CannotSendRequest()

Exception Type: CannotSendRequest at /linkedin/auth
Exception Value:
```

And then, sometimes I get: **BadStatusLine** error instead of this.

It's pretty random. I don't know when or why they happen. **It happens more frequently when I'm running the Django development server (and less frequently when in APACHE2...but it still happens at random times). When this error happens, I have to restart my server.**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925639/httplib-cannotsendrequest-error-in-wsgi)) this happens if you try to reuse an `httplib.HTTP` object which had not been fully used.  Maybe a connection pool in the library you're using, and an exception getting thrown during the request processing?  Suggestion is to create new connection objects every time.