# Python CannotSendRequest

Tags: python, django

I receive a CannotSendRequest in my oauth library (Django socialauth) when I try to connect to Twitter.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/me/webfaction/project/socialauth/views.py" in twitter_login
94.     request_token = twitter.fetch_request_token(callback=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('socialauth_twitter_login_done')))
File "/Users/me/webfaction/project/socialauth/lib/oauthtwitter2.py" in fetch_request_token
50.         return oauth.OAuthToken.from_string(oauth_response(oauth_request))
File "/Users/me/webfaction/project/socialauth/lib/oauthtwitter2.py" in oauth_response
33.     connection().request(req.http_method, req.to_url())
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in   request
914.             self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in _send_request
931.         self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py" in putrequest
818.             raise CannotSendRequest()

Exception Type: CannotSendRequest at /accounts/twitter_login/
Exception Value:
```

Here's where I'm creating the HTTP connection

```
def connection():
    try: 
        return connection._connection
    except AttributeError:
        connection._connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(TWITTER_URL)
    return connection._connection

def oauth_response(req):
    connection().request(req.http_method, req.to_url())
    return connection().getresponse().read()
```

I've searched SO and found these links, but I'm still not sure how to implement the solution. I've tried and failed. Any help would be appreciated.

[httplib CannotSendRequest error in WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925639/httplib-cannotsendrequest-error-in-wsgi)

[When I use httplib for my OAUTH in Python, I always get "CannotSendRequest" and then "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310143/when-i-use-httplib-for-my-oauth-in-python-i-always-get-cannotsendrequest-and-t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925639/httplib-cannotsendrequest-error-in-wsgi) says this error happens when you reuse connections that have thrown an exception and didn't make it to the getresponse() stage.

Indeed, `connection.request("GET", "/")` x 2 throws the error.

The solution suggested is to re-create the connection every time. Is that what you want to do? Note I have no opinions on this matter, you just asked how to implement what's on those posts.

If so, get rid of your `connection()` function and always do

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(TWITTER_URL)
connection.request(req.http_method, req.to_url())
response = connection.getresponse().read()
connection.close()
return response
```

Comment: ah. i forgot to close(). i thought creating a new HTTPConnection object was enough