# Python Selenium error: http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a bit of javascript using the webdriver.execute_script function, below:

```
self.webdriver.execute_script("var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('_3XJPq')[0]; btn.disabled=true; btn.innerHTML='Perform Review'")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 491, in execute_script
'args': converted_args})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 254, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 487, in _request
self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1108, in putrequest
raise CannotSendRequest(self.__state)
```

http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent

Based on some previous questions ([httplib CannotSendRequest error in WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925639/httplib-cannotsendrequest-error-in-wsgi)), it seems like the connection is broken, and I am failing when trying to reuse it. Is there a way in selenium to create a new connection without navigating away from the page?

If it helps, I am using the chrome webdriver.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen for this specific script or any script that you execute using `execute_script`

Comment: Anything using the execute command, actually. It failed with the same error when using the execute to close the browser.