# How to do PUT request in Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-cloud, http.client, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to crawl a website to get the info about vehicles. I want to get all vehicles from that site. I want to repeat the process every day because every day there are new vehicles.

There are a lot of cars, more than 100 thousand. Thus doing it once (in one process) would take too much time and it can't be done in that way.

Thus I need to do it in more smaller processes instead of in one big process.

If I understand correctly that can be done with **IBM Cloud functions**.

I could for example for every make, and for every model of that make call an action to get the list of cars.

That way I would have (instead of one big process) many smaller processes and it would take less time.

The idea is as follows:

- Call an action which will get all `makes` and loop through them. And for every make, first create and action and then call it

The code is as follows:

```
import sys
import os
import json
import requests
import http.client
import uuid

API_URL = "https://url.com"
APIHOST = os.environ.get('__OW_API_HOST')
NAMESPACE = os.environ.get('__OW_NAMESPACE')
USER_PASS = os.environ.get('__OW_API_KEY').split(':')

code = "New function code"

makes = [
    {"id": 9,"name": "Audi"},
    {"id": 74,"name": "Volkswagen"}
]

def main(dict):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("openwhisk.eu-gb.bluemix.net")
    payload = json.dumps({"exec": {"kind": "python-jessie:3", "code": code}})
    headers = {
        'accept': "application/json",
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Basic my-base64key"
    }

    for make in makes:
        action = 'models-{0}'.format(make['name'])
        url = APIHOST + '/api/v1/namespaces/' + NAMESPACE + '/actions/' + action + "?overwrite=true"

        conn.request("PUT", url, payload, headers) // Create new action
        // Execute the new action

    return {"Success": "Main executed correctly."}
```

The problem is in `for` loop. If there is only one make then it works fine. But if there are two or more it doesn't work. I get an error as follows:

```
[
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322665342Z stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322685254Z stderr: File \"pythonrunner.py\", line 88, in run",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322692936Z stderr: exec('fun = %s(param)' % self.mainFn, self.global_context)",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322699124Z stderr: File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322705761Z stderr: File \"__main__.py\", line 71, in main",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322712082Z stderr: File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 1239, in request",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322718524Z stderr: self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322724518Z stderr: File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 1250, in _send_request",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322730924Z stderr: self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322736931Z stderr: File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py\", line 1108, in putrequest",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322742876Z stderr: raise CannotSendRequest(self.__state)",
    "2018-07-11T08:53:06.322748626Z stderr: http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent"
]
```

Any idea how can I do those requests inside for loop if there are two or more records?

Comment: You should get the response before than sending new requests. I think this link may be helpful [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925639/httplib-cannotsendrequest-error-in-wsgi)

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the crawler process into separate action invocations is a sensible approach to running this work on IBM Cloud Functions.

However, it would be better to have a single action that uses event parameters to determine the car make and model to crawl, rather than having a separate action for each make and model.

The code above, which iterates over the model & model list, can then invoke that single action multiple times with different event parameters, rather than trying to creating a new action per item.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve the issue?. For me it looks like the issue with your `http.client` library is not compatible to run inside Cloud Functions due to its asynchronous invocation behavior.

According to Python documentation, you shouldn't use this library directly. Instead use highly recommended `requests` module.

> http.client — HTTP protocol client Source code: Lib/http/client.py
>
> This module defines classes which implement the client side of the
>   HTTP and HTTPS protocols. It is normally not used directly — the
>   module urllib.request uses it to handle URLs that use HTTP and HTTPS.
>
> See also [The Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP
>   client interface.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html